# Yup validation with dynamic keys in an object

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, object, yup

I have an object for validation that might look like this:

```js
const exampleObject = {
  foo: {
    entries: {
      '785bac64-c6ce-4878-bfb8-9cf5b32e2438': {
        name: 'First object',
      },
      '117450da-315b-4676-ad23-edd94a4b6b51': {
        name: 'Second object',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

The keys of the `entries` object are dynamic (uuids). I want to validate that the `name` property in any of those objects is not an empty string. However, `entries` is not required, it is only required that if there *are* any entries, they cannot contain an empty string. How can I do this with Yup?

```js
const exampleObjectValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  foo: Yup.object({
    entries: Yup.object({
      /* what goes here ? */
   })
  })
})
```

Comment: See [this particular comment](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/130#issuecomment-339529746)

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I did it:

```
const exampleObjectValidation = Yup.object()
  .shape({
    foo: Yup.object({
      entries: Yup.lazy((value) => {
        if (!isEmpty(value)) {
          const validationObject = { name: Yup.string().required('Item cannot be empty') }
          const newEntries = Object.keys(value).reduce(
            (acc, val) => ({
              ...acc,
              [val]: Yup.object(validationObject),
            }),
            {}
          )

          return Yup.object().shape(newEntries)
        }
        return Yup.mixed().notRequired()
      }),
    }),
  })
  .nullable()
  .notRequired()
```

Comment: is there a way to validate the key format using this method?